# Why is Business Login for Instagram not working?

Tags: facebook, instagram, instagram-api

I am creating a desktop app which uses Meta's Instagram Graph API. I want a user to log into their instagram account so that the app can use their data. Meta documentation appears to allow you to do this through Business Login for Instagram (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/business-login-for-instagram#before-you-start). Problem is, this is not fully working for me.

In my app on the Meta website, I have the Facebook Login and Instagram Graph API products. I have business verification. I added a redirect url. I created a link for login according to the syntax given: [https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app_id}&display=page&extras=%7B%22setup%22%3A%7B%22channel%22%3A%22IG_API_ONBOARDING%22%7D%7D&redirect_uri=https://google.com/&response_type=token&scope=instagram_basic](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=%7Bapp_id%7D&display=page&extras=%7B%22setup%22%3A%7B%22channel%22%3A%22IG_API_ONBOARDING%22%7D%7D&redirect_uri=https://google.com/&response_type=token&scope=instagram_basic)

I set my app to live mode to test the login link. It made me sign into Facebook, then into Instagram. Problem is, it stalled at instagram. Once I gave my Business Instagram credentials it does nothing. It does not redirect and give me the user access token in the URL fragment like the documentation says. The link works partially, then stops without even giving an error.

I do not know if the problem is I need to request some advanced permissions before this will work all the way through. I don't know if the problem is I am using the same account to test the app which I also created the app with.  I do not know if the problem is that under App Settings > Basic, that I never added a platform. A platform is necessary to request advanced permissions, but I am unsure if I need to request advanced permissions to begin with. Also none of the platform options they give are for a desktop app.  If anyone has any knowledge on how to get this to work, that would be greatly helpful.

Edit:
This is where login process gets stalled at. You press "Get Started", it loads Instagram Login pop up. Once you log in, the pop up disappears and you're still stuck on this screen.

[image]

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow/#login regarding `redirect_uri`: _"If you are using this in a webview within a desktop app, this must be set to `https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`."_

Comment: I am currently not using a webview. Right now, I am just testing login through a browser, but that is useful information to know for a webview.

Comment: _"Right now, I am just testing login through a browser"_ - then you will have to add the "Website" platform in your app settings.

Comment: I haven't made an actual website to test, I was just using the Business Instagram url above in a browser to test and to see what happens at the end. If I just stick with a webview in the app, will I need to chose a platform?

Comment: Couldn't tell you, never created a desktop app in this environment. But I suppose you have to add _some_ platform, and Website is really the only thing I can even remotely see make sense.

Comment: The scope for my login link, as shown above, is instagram_basic. I just realized I never requested advanced access for instagram_basic. Could that be the reason it is not working? I'm wondering if it was that simple of a mistake.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I did login with regular FB account and it works. The only thing I got at conole is: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://www.facebook.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://web.facebook.com').

Comment: @jari85 were you able to figure it out? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: Same issue here. After log in the popup just disappears and nothing happens.